# Array Filter in forEach Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter our all JSON objects in that are empty. The below tells me which ones are empty, but I am unable to get the .filter function to return the same data since I have to filter on obj.children and not just obj.

Using the below json_data, it should filter out Newmar. There is another parent level above this, hence the use of the 1st .children.forEach.

```js
var testF = json_data.children.forEach(obj => {

  if (obj.children.length != 0) {
    obj.children.forEach(
      obj => {
        if (obj.children.length != 0) {
          console.log(obj)
        } else {
          console.log("EMPTY")
        }
      })
  }
});

json_data = {
  "name": "WINNEBAGO",
  "description": "",
  "free": true,
  "url": "https://www.winnebago.com/",
  "children": [{
      "name": "WINNEBAGO",
      "description": "",
      "url": "https://www.winnebago.com/",
      "free": true,
      "children": [{
          "name": "ADVENTURER",
          "description": "CLASS A",
          "url": "https://www.winnebago.com/models/product/motorhomes/class-a/adventurer",
          "free": true,
          "type": "5"
        },
        {
          "name": "ADVENTURER AE",
          "description": "CLASS A",
          "url": "https://www.winnebago.com/models/product/motorhomes/accessibility-enhanced/adventurer-ae",
          "free": true,
          "type": "5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "GRAND DESIGN RV",
      "description": "",
      "url": "https://www.granddesignrv.com/",
      "free": true,
      "children": [{
          "name": "TRANSCEND XPLOR",
          "description": "TRAVEL TRAILER",
          "url": "https://www.granddesignrv.com/showroom/2022/travel-trailer/transcend-xplor",
          "free": true,
          "type": "2"
        },
        {
          "name": "IMAGINE",
          "description": "TRAVEL TRAILER",
          "url": "https://www.granddesignrv.com/showroom/2022/travel-trailer/imagine",
          "free": true,
          "type": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "NEWMAR",
      "description": "",
      "url": "https://www.newmarcorp.com/",
      "free": true,
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The data is a single object with a `children` array prop. The children in that array themselves have a `children` prop.  The OP code starts with `json_data.children.forEach(...` which means the loop should only check one more level of children, but it tries to check children's children, which are all empty.

Comment: RVs...childArray(I've filtered out empty here)...childArray(I am trying to filter empty here)...nodes

Answer (score 0):

do you mean

```js
const filterChildren = json_data.children.filter(obj => obj.children.length > 0)
const json_data_new = {...json_data, children: filterChildren}
```

Comment: I have 4 levels. RVs...childArray...childArray...nodes
I need to filter out empty in the 2nd childArray. This looks to be doing what I have done which is filter out the 1st childArray.